# prove f is continous with given limit and squence

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

f is defined on all R and a $\in$ R,
Prove if $\lim_{n \to \infty}(f(p+a_n)-f(p-a_n)) = 0$ and all sequences $\{a_n\}$ converges to 0, then f is countinous at p.

what I have now is $\lim_{n \to \infty}(f(p+a_n)) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(f(p+a_n))$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(p+a_n) = p+0=p$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}(f(p+a_n)) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(f(p+a_n))=f(p)$
But I don't know how to go further.

Comment: What have you tried? Your question may be closed as homework if you don't show your working.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Let $p=0$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$ for $x \neq 0, f(0)=1$. Then $f$ is not continuous at $p$ but $f(p+a_n)-f(p-a_n)=0$ for all $n$.